# Detener tarea java que se crea con un crontrigger de quartz

Tags: java, trigger, quartz, crontrigger

he creado un programa que crea y registra un `crontrigger` y lo ejecuta de forma correcta, sin embargo al finalizar las iteraciones del proceso de acuerdo a `cron` la tarea java creada en el Sistema Operativo (SO) no se detiene, sigue activa y da la situación que el `cron` no se va a volver a ejecutar nunca.

He creado la clase job

```
public class SimpleJob extends Job {
  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext arg0) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println(String.format("Hora de ejecución --> %s", LocalDateTime.now().toString()));
  }
}
```

En la clase principal creo el job, el trigger y el schedule

```
public class App {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    try {
      JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SimpleJob.class)
                      .withIdentity("Job1", "Grupo1")
                      .build();
      Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
                        .withIdentity("trigger1", "Grupo1")
                           .withSchedule(cronSheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/10 05 16 11 8 ? 2021"))
                        .build();
      Scheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.getDefaultSheduler();
      scheduler.start();
      scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

De acuerdo al `cronSchedule` el `job` se ejecuta cada 10 segundos por un lapso de un minuto en una fecha especifica, Al finalizar los 6 jobs la tarea java creada en el SO deberia finalizar también pero esto no sucede la tarea java sigue activa.

He adicionado las líneas de código

```
Thread.sleep(10000L);
scheduler.shutdown();
```

Pero esto ocasiona que la tarea java finalice a los 10 segundos de haber lanzado el proceso lo cual hace que el `job` se ejecute una única vez y no las seis veces que se requieren.

Si el valor de milisegundos en el `Thread` es de 60000, si se alcanzan a ejecutar, sin embargo esto es un prototipo para procesos que el crontab debe durar una semana por lo cual el valor en el método `sleep` del `Thread` sería de 864000000 aproximadamente.

Hay alguna forma de enviar el `scheduler.shutdown()` únicamente cuando el `cron` se haya finalizado en su totalidad sin necesidad de colocar el `Thread.sleep()`;